# How do I email an address link from an iOS app and then search for it in Google maps

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-maps

I'm trying to send an address from an iOS app to an email recipient. I would like that address to link to a Google Map search in Safari/browser

Here's what I have so far. I'm wondering how to use the address to search through the map:

```
 NSString *myUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.co.uk/%@", addressLb.text];

NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I'm at %@ on %@. Come join me... %@", nameLb.text, addressLb.text, myUrl];
```

one problem I'm having is that the address in addressLB.text has spacing. so, `NSString *myUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"maps.google.co.uk/?q=%@";, addressLb.text];` will search for maps.google.co.uk/?q=1600 and drop the Pennsylvania

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add /maps?q= followed by the address using a plus (+) in place of spaces to the end of the google maps url.  For example, to find 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC:

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=1600+Pennsylvania+Avenue,+Washington,+DC

Comment: thanks. one problem I'm having is that the address in addressLB.text has spacing. so,     NSString *myUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.co.uk/?q=%@", addressLb.text];
will search for https://maps.google.co.uk/?q=1600 and drop the Pennsylvania

Comment: just replace the spaces with + 
[addressLb.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

Comment: Use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` to change all spaces to +.  E.g., `    NSString *whiteHouseAddressWithSpaces = @"1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC";
    NSString *whiteHouseAddressWithPluses = [whiteHouseAddressWithSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];`